# Web Form and MVC Application is throwing Internal Server Error 500 while storing data in SQL Server

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, web-services

I am probably repeating same issue discussed on forum but I think this issue should be discussed as it persist with many ways I tried.

I have referred number of links including

1. http://weblogs.asp.net/jalpeshpvadgama/calling-an-asp-net-web-service-from-jquery
2. http://codepedia.info/2016/01/insert-data-using-jquery-ajax-in-asp-net-csharp-database-ms-sql-server/

Here first one works for me but second is not working so tried it with WebForm and MVC with and without [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]. Virtually, It became hit and trail case for me. Also, my Fiddler Tool says JSON is correctly supplied in every case when I tried single value or multiple. Last but not least there are lots of resources over the web that how achieve AJAX jQuery but merely some specific thing I found how to debug with Inter Server Error. Any note will be appreciable.

In my ASP.NET MVC application

Services is Like :

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class SaveDb : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string InsertIntoDB(string p)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=127.0.0.1;Initial Catalog=School;Integrated Security=True");
                sqlConnection.Open();

                SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("insert into UserNamePassword values('uNm1','" + p + "')");
                sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                sqlConnection.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return "Error";
            }

            return "success";
        }
    }
```

HTML View is Like :

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#btn').on('click', function (e) {

                e.preventDefault();
                var p = $('#p1').val();

                var jsonData = JSON.stringify({ p: p });

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'MVCP/SaveDb.asmx/InsertIntoDB',
                    data: jsonData,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: OnSuccess,
                    error: OnErrorCall
                })

                function OnSuccess(response) {
                    var result = response.d;
                    if (result == "success") {
                        alert('Job Done');
                    }
                }

                function OnErrorCall(response) {
                    alert('failed agin');
                }
            })
        })

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    User Name
    <br />

    Password <input id="p1" type="text" />
    <br />

    <button id="btn">Click</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Note : Putting a break point over the Service Page is not received control and Explicitly loading the Service on Browser and passing the p Parameter worked. So, I guess guess Err is coming from Web Service Part thus adding Web Service Tag/ WCF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And..! This Code is working absolutely fine.

.ASPX Page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("[id*=btnSave]").bind("click", function () {
            var user = {};
            user.Username = $("[id*=txtUsername]").val();
            user.Password = $("[id*=txtPassword]").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "CS.aspx/SaveUser",
                data: '{user: ' + JSON.stringify(user) + '}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    alert("User has been added successfully.");
                    window.location.reload();
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

.ASPX.cs Page

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod]
    public static void SaveUser(User user)
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Users VALUES(@Username, @Password)"))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", user.Username);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", user.Password);
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
public class User
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying you solved your problem?  If so, mark your answer as answered.